# Nonetype object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, attributeerror, nonetype

```
    global twitter_user_info
    twitter_user_info=[]    

    def get_user_info(twitter_user):
    """
    An example of using the query_user_info method
    :param twitter_user: the twitter user to capture user data
    :return: twitter_user_data: returns a dictionary of twitter user data
    """

    user_info = query_user_info(user=twitter_user)
    twitter_user_data = {}

    twitter_user_data["user"] = user_info.user
    twitter_user_data["fullname"] = user_info.full_name
    twitter_user_data["location"] = user_info.location
    twitter_user_data["blog"] = user_info.blog
    twitter_user_data["date_joined"] = user_info.date_joined
    twitter_user_data["id"] = user_info.id
    twitter_user_data["num_tweets"] = user_info.tweets
    twitter_user_data["following"] = user_info.following
    twitter_user_data["followers"] = user_info.followers
    twitter_user_data["likes"] = user_info.likes
    twitter_user_data["lists"] = user_info.lists

    return twitter_user_data

    absd=[]
    def main():
      start = time.time()
      csv = pd.read_csv('operationbandar_users.csv')
      users = csv['username']
      pool = Pool(4)

      for user in pool.map(get_user_info,users):
        twitter_user_info.append(user)

      cols=['id','fullname','date_joined','location','blog', 'num_tweets','following','followers','likes','lists']
      data_frame = pd.DataFrame(twitter_user_info, index=absd, columns=cols)
      data_frame.index.name = "Users"
      data_frame.sort_values(by="followers", ascending=False, inplace=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
      elapsed = time.time() - start
      print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed}")
      display(data_frame)
```

This code is returning the following error:

> multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
>   """
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/nrjkumar/anaconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
>       result = (True, func(*args, *kwds))
>     File "/home/nrjkumar/anaconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
>       return list(map(*args))
>     File "examples/get_twitter_user_data_1.py", line 43, in get_user_info
>      **twitter_user_data["user"] = user_info.user**
>   **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'**
>   """
>   The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "examples/get_twitter_user_data_1.py", line 89, in 
>       main()
>     File "examples/get_twitter_user_data_1.py", line 66, in main
>       for user in pool.map(get_user_info,users):
>     File "/home/nrjkumar/anaconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
>       return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>     File "/home/nrjkumar/anaconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
>       raise self._value
>   **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'**

I have searched here for possible cases with pool.map and passing dictionary as parameter but couldn't find the issue. I am a newbie to python. Can anybody help?

> query_user_info()

```
def query_user_info(user):
"""
Returns the scraped user data from a twitter user page.

:param user: the twitter user to web scrape its twitter page info
"""
try:
    user_info = query_user_page(INIT_URL_USER.format(u=user))
    if user_info:
        logger.info("Got user information from username {}".format(user))
        return user_info

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logger.info("Program interrupted by user. Returning user information gathered so far...")
except BaseException:
    logger.exception("An unknown error occurred! Returning user information gathered so far...")

logger.info("Got user information from username {}".format(user))
return user_info
```

> query_user_page()

```
def query_user_page(url, retry=10, timeout=60):
"""
Returns the scraped user data from a twitter user page.

:param url: The URL to get the twitter user info from (url contains the user page)
:param retry: Number of retries if something goes wrong.
:return: Returns the scraped user data from a twitter user page.
"""
print("reached url:",url)

try:
    proxy = next(proxy_pool)
    logger.info('Using proxy {}'.format(proxy))
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER, proxies={"http": proxy})
    html = response.text or ''

    user_info = User.from_html(html)
    if not user_info:
        return None

    return user_info

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    logger.exception('HTTPError {} while requesting "{}"'.format(
        e, url))
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    logger.exception('ConnectionError {} while requesting "{}"'.format(
        e, url))
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    logger.exception('TimeOut {} while requesting "{}"'.format(
        e, url))

if retry > 0:
    logger.info('Retrying... (Attempts left: {})'.format(retry))
    return query_user_page(url, retry-1)

logger.error('Giving up.')
return None
```

Comment: It looks like `query_user_info()` is returning None. Can you show that method's code?

Comment: So somehow i debugged the code and found some of the values returned by query_user_info are none. How can i bypass these None values?

Comment: Can you give me the exact response from the method? What do you . mean some of the values are None? I'd expect either user_info to be None or it to work. Also, in all of your exceptions, you are just logging it but continuing execution. So it could return None if an exception is raised without actually retrying